# How often does Locu push their data to Yelp and other providers?

Tags: local-seo, data

I'm not generally a fan of GoDaddy products, but I may end up having to recommend their "Get Found" product to a client.  GoDaddy have recently gobbled up Locu and are now the source of menu data for such big players as Yelp.  "Get Found" seems to be the only place to update this data.

Before I recommend it to the client, does anyone know how quickly the data from this service gets pushed to subscriber sites and apps such as Yelp? This restaurant changes their menu every day, so if it's not instantaneous it's not very helpful.

Comment: You may have to ask them. I rather suspect you can call the support line and ask the question there. In all the years I have used GoDaddy, I have never had a problem with them or tech support though sometime the one answering the phone does not have the answer and has to refer to someone who does.

Comment: No luck getting a definitive answer from their support.  Was hoping someone here might have first hand experience with the service.

Comment: Okay. Sorry. I was hoping that would be a valid avenue for you. I get that GoDaddy's ala' carte approach really adds up and any hesitation for signing up yet another "thing" from GoDaddy. I used them as a webhost when they started and it was all much more stream-lined back then. They were easy and cheap and much better than net-sol! I wish I had an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the Locu site itself once you have managed your info and click a certain button the data is pushed out at that time to all the networks in needs to be shared to. How long it takes those networks to update their own records is really dependant on them however Locu seems to indicate that it is a very short amount of time to push the data out to the networks.